# Which class loader will be parent of class loader created inside a thread?

Tags: java, classloader

Suppose my application class loader is **CL_A**.

I have a user class loader **CL_B** , obvious child of **CL_A**.

Now my application is running in a Thread associated with **CL_B** class loader.And inside this thread I have one more User class loader **CL_C**.

Now which class loader **CL_A** or **CL_B** is the parent class loader of **CL_C** ? If **CL_B**,why not CL_A ?

Comment: Just wondering: if you already have the code at that; why don't you run it to figure what is going on?

Comment: I have code which is doing that,but my question is more on why CL_B.And how to change parent class loader of CL_C ---- CL_B to CL_A and is it possible to do such change.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is CL_B as each classloader's parent is the classloader that loaded the class that initialized the classloader. Each classloader only knows his direct parent.

The only important thing is, that your thread's class gets loaded by CL_B, then CL_C's parent is CL_B.